# Javascript getElementByID for asp:Image returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to find the control and display set to "block" or "none" on onclientselectedindexchanged event of RadCombobox. It returns always null. The script and controls are in User Control of Content page. There is also Master page for this Content page. I  debugged the code with Debugger statement but the control has this tag. "ctl00_content2_ucControl1_imgTest". How can show and hide image? Please let me know. Thanks for your help. Also I tried to use document.getElementById("<%=imgTest.ClientID"); and $find(("<%=imgTest.ClientID") ; but none of these working.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgTest" ImageUrl="../../../images/test.gif" AlternateText="test"
                            runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:Image>

<telerik:RadComboBox ID="Combobox1" runat="server" DataTextField="test1"
                            DataValueField="test_id" NoWrap="true" Width="250" onclientselectedindexchanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">                        </telerik:RadComboBox>


<script type="text/javascript">
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) { 
     {
      var item = eventArgs.get_item(); 
          if(item.get_value() == "8") 
             {
            var imageControl = document.getElementById('imgTest');
            imageControl.style.display = "block"; 
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imgTest is a server control, so the client id will be automatically generated by the server.

Change this line:

```
var imageControl = document.getElementById('imgTest');
```

to:

```
var imageControl = document.getElementById('<%=imgTest.ClientId%>');
```

The issue with your previous attempts was the missing end tag `%>`

Comment: Welcome.  Make sure you upvote and accept correct answers for future readers and your own rep points.

Comment: +1 for you and offerred an additional solution to fix the problem depending on the actual .net version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .net 4.0 you can set the `ClientIDMode='Static'` and then your code should work fine as intended as long as you aren't in a repeatable element.

Here is some more info on how to use the ClientIDMode:
http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx